# How to recursively execute brute force method

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

I'm trying to create a recursive algorithm using brute force. This algorithm is suppose to compare integers and "edit the distance" if the integers compared aren't similar. Example: 3254 should be 2345. The editDistance here would be 2 [(3,2)(5,4)].

My code compiles but it doesn't give me any output. If anyone could help me troubleshoot it would be appreciated greatly.

```
public static int measureEditDistance(int[] rankings) {
    int editDistance = 0;
    int R = rankings.length;

    // You need to write this method.
    //   Add your logic here to compute the editDistance

    for (int m = 0; m < R; m++) {
        for (int i = m + 1; i < R; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < R; j++) {
                if (rankings[m] + rankings[i] + rankings[j] == 0) {
                    editDistance++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return editDistance;
}
```

Comment: Please paste your code as text and not as an image

Comment: @Mureinik but why did you inline the image anyway? That teaches OP the wrong lesson. The screenshot is worth nothing.

Comment: copy the code to your post, remove the image. Did you find it quicker to take a screenshot, upload it and copy the link rather than copying the code directly?

Comment: I don't understand the question. why should 3254 be 2345? And what is recursive about it?

Comment: You don't see any output because it's not printed. Google to find out how to print information in Java

Comment: I think that was the question, not Is this recursive? but How to recursively execute brute force method

Comment: First of all Your code is not recursive, For a function to be recursive, the function has to call itself again. It is going into multiple level of loops and returning the editDistance. Secondly, I do not see any System.out.print() in the given code snippet. Do you have print statements elsewhere?

Comment: Hes not asking IS THIS RECURSIVE PEOPLE how is no one understanding this he is asking how to make it recursive

Comment: @andrew  Before I can help with an answer, is TRUE bruteforce required (if answer is wrong drop everything and try a new one)? or could you optimize it a bit to not swap digits once they are in the correct position?

Comment: What's in the ranking array ?

Comment: Added an answer for you, let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Have you tried a debugger yet? Add some test-output. Try to follow the steps for a small example by hand with pen and paper and compare the steps with the debug-output-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A true brute force method would require you to find all permutations of the given number.  So here are the methods to do that (recursively):

```
void swap(int[] arr, int x, int y) {
    int temp = arr[x];
    arr[x] = arr[y];
    arr[y] = temp;
}


void permute(int[] arr) {
    permute(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
}


void permute(int[] arr, int i, int n) {
    int j;
    if (i == n)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    else {
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++) {
            swap(arr, i, j);
            permute(arr, i + 1, n);
            swap(arr, i, j); // backtrack
        }
    }
}
```

After that you would have to test for your condition, which is that your `ranking` array is in the same order as some other array which we will call `temp`.  so above the methods we add the following.

```
int temp[] = {3, 2, 4, 5};
```

So we can check. we must change the code of `permute(int[])` to:

```
int permute(int[] arr, int[] rankings){
    int distancevar = 0;
    distance var = permute(arr,rankings,0,arr.length-1);
    return distancevar;

}
```

Then we will have to change the return type of `permute(int[], int, int)` to `int` so that we can return the distance we found to be true.  This will make the code as follows:

```
int permute(int[] arr, int[] rankings, int i, int n) {
    int j;
    int ans = 0;
    bool isAns = false;
    if (i == n)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    else {
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++) {
            swap(arr, i, j);
            isAns = check(arr, rankings);
            if(isAns){
                **here you would call your distance check on the two arrays, 
    which I am still unsure of what you actually are doing here**
                ans = *some distance calc*;
                return ans;
            }
            ans = permute(arr,rankings, i + 1, n);
            if (ans == 0){
                swap(arr, i, j); // backtrack
                isAns = check(arr, rankings);
                if(isAns){
                    **here you would call your distance check on the two arrays, 
        which I am still unsure of what you actually are doing here**
                    ans = *some distance calc*;
                    return ans;
                }
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Now in your permutation function, test the array against your condition.

```
bool check(int[] arr, int[] ans)
    int same = 0
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
        if(temp[i] == ans[i])
            same++;
    if (same == 4)
        return true;
    return false;
```

Once these functions are complete the only code that should be in `main` would be as follows

```
int ans = permute(*your array to test*, *final array desired*);
System.out.println(ans);
```

**Explanation**

Notice how the permute function calls itself and returns `ans` where `ans = distance_value`.  That value is then passed back through ALL of the function calls.  This is recursion.

Comment: @Andrew I hope this helps friend. Let me know if the code doesn't work for you and I'll  edit or take it down.

Comment: Just edited it to fix a flaw in the logic.  was returning the wrong answer, likely 0 each time before.